# Disable EF core query optimizer

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a query that contains this code as a part of the query:

```
from ShiftPeriod s in DbSet<ShiftPeriod>
select s.DateFrom).Max() == [e].DateFrom
```

This is copied form EF log (Compiling query model). But after that there is Optimized query model in log which shows this:

```
from ShiftPeriod d in DbSet<ShiftPeriod>
where !([d].Deleted)
select s.DateFrom).Max() == [d].DateFrom
```

See how `s.DateFrom` is used instead of `d.DateFrom`. 
And I get error saying:

> variable 's' of type 'EDD.Domain.Model.Shifts.ShiftPeriod' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined

I want to know if I can somehow turn off this optimizer or if there is any other way of fixing this?